# ReactJS: Variable in useState not updating in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have the following:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [open2, setOpen2] = useState(false);

  let intervalID;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
       intervalID = setInterval(() => {
       const formSubmitButton = document.querySelector(".btnaa");
       console.log(open);
       formSubmitButton.click();
       }, 1500);
  }
  }, [editing]);
```

and then:

```
<DesktopDatePicker
open={open}
onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
style={{ width: '100%' }}
label={"Date From"}
inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
disablePast
value={item.DateFrom == '' ? item.DateFrom : new Date(item.DateFrom).toISOString()}
onChange={handleChangeFrom}
renderInput={(params) => <TextFields {...params} fullWidth onClick={(e) => setOpen(true)} onKeyDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()} />}
/>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to run the formSubmitButton.click() only if open is false. When opening the DesktopDatePicker it still returns false even though it is open (and hence should return true)

How do I get the formSubmitButton.click() to only trigger when open is false? So I don't want it triggering if DesktopDatePicker is open.

Comment: You can add `open` to the dependency array of `useEffect` to clear the interval when `open` is true and only start the interval when `editing` is true and `open` is false.
And you might want to read how closures work in javascript.

Comment: @Martin - if I add open to [editing] then it returns true when opening the date picker, but also constantly returns false as well... how do I clear the interval?

Comment: [MDN clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

Comment: @Martin - thanks, that clears it and will implement, but for now I am still alternating in the console between false and true continuously.

Comment: Placing a console.log(open) after the useEffect shows the correct true/false value. But then placing the same console.log within the setInterval shows false always

Comment: Lastly, as soon as I try to click through to next month on the date picker, it closes the date picker and returns false

Answer (score 0):

Does TextFields accepts a onClick prop? What happens i you just onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}?

Then if it accepts i would just pass setOpen to TextFields onClick={setOpen} and use it inside the component.

If you use some kind of component library, that would be worth mentioning it to get better help.

Comment: Using onClick={setOpen} returns the error: You must not mix controlling and uncontrolled mode for `open` prop